# Docker login replacement when using buildctl

Tags: docker

I'm running `buildctl` inside my k8s pod to build an image. Since [docker socket doesn't exist anymore](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dockershim-faq/) I can't use `docker login` with my credentials. Is there a way to login to docker hub so I won't hit any rate limits when pulling images without using `docker login` command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buildkit doesn't depend on the docker engine. It is reading the credentials directly from the config file:

> If credentials are required, `buildctl` will attempt to read Docker configuration file `$DOCKER_CONFIG/config.json`. `$DOCKER_CONFIG` defaults to `~/.docker`.

Source: https://github.com/moby/buildkit

So if you mount a docker login secret into the container where you run the `buildctl` command, it should be used.

Comment: But how can I tell that when an image is pulled from dockerhub that its using the credentials?

Comment: Try pulling from a private repo.